# Connection to a MySQL database through proxy

Tags: c#, mysql, database, proxy

We have created an app. that allows people to work with data in a MySQL database. Everything works well for the people with static IPs as we have just added their IPs to a cleared list on the database.

Problem is 1 person with a dynamic IP. His IP changes all over the place, so we can't clear his IP without adding a %.%.%.% filter to the database (which we will not do for obvious reasons).

Instead, we are thinking that this person can run the app. through a proxy or connect to the MySQL database through a proxy (thereby giving us only 1 static IP to clear).

But how do we do that? I haven't been able to find any instructions/C# code for making an app. run through a proxy or letting an MySQL database connect through a proxy.